# Elastic search paginating on multiple types in an index

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, full-text-search, search-suggestion

I have an index with multiple types like below :

- songs
- books
- movies

I am building an API for suggesting indexed items grouped by their type, The problem is that I want a `size` functionality inside each aggregation, Just like the `completion suggester` approach which returns an exact number of items for each type. I ended up with multi index query approach to query each type separately, Is there any better approach to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each aggregation you specify can have a filter associated with it, so you could
reduce the context of an aggregation to a specific type that way. Additionally,
you can use the `filters` aggregation to create buckets for each filter, and run
an aggregation with a certain size on each sub-bucket, like this:

`GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "alltypes": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "songs": {"term": {"_type": "songs"}},
          "books": {"term": {"_type": "books"}},
          "movies": {"term": {"_type": "movies"}}
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        ... your aggregation for each individual type here ...
      }
    }
  }
}`

More info about the `filters` aggregation can be found at
http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html

Hopefully that helps, let me know if I misunderstood your question (it was a
little uncertain whether you were talking about suggestors or aggregations since
both were mentioned in the question).

Comment: Thanks, I exactly needed the solution for aggregation with definite number of size on each bucket.